# Declaring delegate with excluded parameter

Tags: c#

I have a function like

```
public void foo(string st; bool x)
```

And I have to pass it as a delegate to EventHandler this way:

```
eventhndl += foo
```

But, it needs 1 parameter less.
How do I make a delegate *excluding* parameter by already declaring the value it has to get, like in following (not working) example:

```
eventhndl += foo(x=true)
```

without getting error with ammount of params?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lambda to bind the parameter like this:

```
eventHandler += s => foo(s, true);
```

Comment: Does not work with this case. "Delegate does not take 1 arguments"

Comment: @Hypixus Then apparently, contrary to what you said in your question, this event handler doesn't take one argument. You'll need to have the anonymous method match the actual delegate of that event.

Comment: @Hypixus Well then the solution would be taking all the parameters, e.g. `eventHandler += (str, x) => foo(str, true);`

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek Yes, now it works! everything was just more parameters, in final code: Radio.StateChanged += (Radio radio, object sender) => radioEvent(radio, sender, false);

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: you can't

Long answer: A delegate represents a function signature so it must match exactly the function to which the instance points to.

To solve this you can use the old way on C# for optional parameters, overloads:

```
void myFunction(bool a, bool b)
{
}

void myFunction(bool a)
{
    myFunction(a, true);
}

delegate myDelegate(bool a);
event myDelegate myEvent;
//...

myEvent += myFunction;
```

In this way you can also use the overload on other places of your code.

Or if you prefer more concise but less readable code, then you can always use a lambda:

```
myEvent += (a) => myFunction(a, true);
```